# How to find the imported files in a file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a `index.js` file where I have the following imports.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Button from 'components/shared/Button';
import Header from 'components/main/Header';
import Footer from 'components/main/Footer';
import Nav from 'components/shared/Nav';
```

What's the best way to find out to all the import statement with `components/shared` or `components/main` in node script?
I am trying to find an object  of components are imported in the `index.js`. For example , form this `index.js` I should get an object using the sript as

```
 {
  "Button": "components/shared/Button",
  "Header": "components/main/Header",
  "Footer": "components/main/Footer",
  "Nav": "components/shared/Nav"
 }
```

Comment: Have your `index.js` export an object in the format you want.

Comment: Search in files (with a software like VSCode, Notepad++ or even grep) with this regex : `/import (.+?) from ['"](.+?)['"]`/

Comment: @brad, ahh, I can't change anything  the `index.js`. And there 300 `index.js` like this, not really possible I am guessing.

Comment: @SubhenduKundu If you're not writing this file, then what exactly are you trying to do?  You can't reliably reflect into another module.

Comment: So I am doing a POC on making this components  which are used mostly lot of places more then 10 places I will add them in a scoped package. More of a hybrid microfrontend strategy. Might sound silly, but wanted to try this.

Comment: @Seblor, I am not an expert with regex, I tried to get all of the file using `var arr = /import (.+?) from ['"](.+?)['"]/g.exec(str);` but getting only the first match. Is there a way to get all? Also how can I update regex with includes only which has `shared` or `main`?

Comment: I just quickly added setup https://repl.it/@subhendukundu/import-regex

Answer (score 2):

[Precinct](https://github.com/dependents/node-precinct) is incredibly useful for this.

```
import { paperwork } from 'precinct';
console.log( paperwork( './index.js' ) );
```

In addition to javascript it can also find imported files in typescript, css, sass, less, stylus...